# What is the difference between BasicHttpRequest and HttpGet, HttpPost, etc in Apache HTTP Client 4.3 ?

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am creating HTTP request using Apache HTTP Client version 4.3.4. I see there are some classes like HttpGet,... and there is also a class BasicHttpRequest. I am not sure which one to use.
Whats the difference and which one should be used in which condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BasicHttpRequest` is provided by the core library. As its name suggests it is pretty basic: it enforces no particular method name or type, nor does it attempt to validate the request URI. The URI parameter can be any arbitrary garbage. HttpClient will dutifully transmit it to server as is, if it is unable to parse it to a valid URI.

`HttpUriRequest` variety on the other hand will enforce specific method type and will require a valid URI. Another important feature is that HttpUriRequest can be aborted at any point of their execution.

You should always be using classes that implement `HttpUriRequest` per default.

Comment: I was hoping @oleg would chime in

Answer (score 0):

I was just browsing the 4.3.6 javadoc attempting to locate your BasicHttpRequest and was unable to find it. Do you have a reference to the javadoc of this class?

I would be under the impression that BasicHttpRequest would be a base class providing operations and attributes common to more than one HttpRequest. It may be extremely generic for extension purposes.

To the first part of your question, use HttpGet, HttpPost etc for their specific operations.  If you only need to HTTP/GET information then use HttpGet, if you need to post a form or document body, then use HttpPost. If you are attempting to use things like the Head, Put, Delete method, then use the correspoding HttpXXX class.

Comment: Thanks @Dave.. I understand HttpXXXX classes should be used for specific operations. But in my scenario, I read HTTP method name, httpversion,etc from file as a string and BasicHttpRequest has constructor which takes method name so need to first check method name and then create corresponding request object. Well, of-course that's not the only advantage I would look but I am curious to know the differences and limitations of these classes (if any) sighting my future needs.
Here's [Documentation](http://goo.gl/vNolxL) and [Tutorial](http://goo.gl/5OAkw)

Comment: Correction : 
BasicHttpRequest has constructor which takes method name so *no* need to first check method name and then create corresponding request object